# problems with torchmetrics import while trying to import whisperx

Tags: python, dependencies, whisper

I'm trying to import whisperx to my colab notebook. I already installed the package, and it worked well, until I made some changes to the notebook (that I cannot trace back, but I guess other packages downloads). Now I am having the following error while trying to import whisperx:

```py
----> 1 import whisperx

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyannote/audio/tasks/segmentation/mixins.py in <module>
     37 from torchaudio.backend.common import AudioMetaData
     38 from torchmetrics import Metric
---> 39 from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryAUROC, MulticlassAUROC, MultilabelAUROC
     40 
     41 from pyannote.audio.core.task import Problem

ImportError: cannot import name 'BinaryAUROC' from 'torchmetrics.classification' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torchmetrics/classification/__init__.py)
```

I already tried upgrading to the latest stable version of torchmetrics, and downgrading to 10.0 or 8.0 and 6.0 (as suggested on web)).

Any suggestion will be appreciated!